# How it is possible to zend creating object of Zend framework model in controller or view?

Tags: php, zend-framework

My question is: If we create any object of one class, that class file  should be included in our file `.In` zend frame work. How is this possible without including that file?

example:
If I have `indexcontrolle`r in controller folder and Article model with name `Article.php` in model folder then how is articale.php available in index controller?

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

```
  private $_model;

  public function indexAction() {

  $model=new Model_Article();/*how it is possible where and when this file include in index controller */

   }
}
?>
```

sorry for my poor English

Comment: you mean autoloading?

Comment: The problem is that ZF1 doesn't have a good autoloading system. You'll have to mannually include this on the file...

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using zf1 version not zf2 , you can do it with,

```
 $model = new Application_Model_Article();
```

where article.php is  under model folder.

you can call this in any of the controller and any of the action.
then you can use for example $model->fetchAll(); to Invoke any function of your model..

Answer (score 0):

[Zend Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) is responsible for automatic class loading. It uses `__autoload`. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.oop5.autoload.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.autoload.php).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer